Cross elasticity of demand with logistic regression
First post, be nice  I'm trying to calculate the cross elasticity of demand. The basic economic concept is simple, but when trying to implement it, I see a range of different methods/equations, which all give different results. Can anyone provide some insight?
A sample of my data is:



Brand
Price_1
Price_2
Price_3
Price_4
Price_5




2
1.5
1.9
1.99
2.09
2.67


5
1.39
1.9
1.91
2.12
2.62


1
1.47
1.9
1.99
1.97
2.67


4
1.21
1.35
1.99
2.16
2.68


2
1.46
1.88
1.97
1.89
2.37



The prices refer to the price of brand 1 through 5; brand is which brand was purchased in this instance. I have ~15k rows.
Using a basic LogReg:
X = df[['Price_1', 'Price_2', 'Price_3', 'Price_4', 'Price_5']]
y = df['Brand']
lr = LogisticRegression(solver='sag')
lr.fit(X,y)
coefs = lr.coef_

I want to test for prices from 1.00 to 3.00, i.e. price_range = np.arange(1.00, 3.01, 0.01).
In this case, I want to measure the cross elasticity of demand on 5 based on price changes in 4.
One method I found involves taking the average of each price excluding the target brand, then predicting the elasticity using predict_proba and an elasticity formula (note the different pe formulae for the brand and the cross-brand)
df_b4 = pd.DataFrame(index = np.arange(price_range.size))
df_b4['Price_1'] = df['Price_1'].mean()
df_b4['Price_2'] = df['Price_2'].mean()
df_b4['Price_3'] = df['Price_3'].mean()
df_b4['Price_4'] = price_range
df_b4['Price_5'] = df['Price_5'].mean()
predict_b4 = lr.predict_proba(df_c4b4)
pr_b4 = predict_b4[:][:,3]
pe_b4 = coefs.iloc[3,3] * price_range * (1-pr_b4)

df_b4xb5 = pd.DataFrame(index = np.arange(price_range.size))
df_b4xb5['Price_1'] = df['Price_1'].mean()
df_b4xb5['Price_2'] = df['Price_2'].mean()
df_b4xb5['Price_3'] = df['Price_3'].mean()
df_b4xb5['Price_4'] = df['Price_4'].mean()
df_b4xb5['Price_5'] = price_range
predict_b4xb5 = lr_brand.predict_proba(df_b4xb5)
pr_b4xb5 = predict_b4xb5[:][:,4]
pe_b4xb5 = -coefs.iloc[3,3] * price_range * pr_b4xb5

This method uses the same coef for calculating the cross elasticity. However, another source I saw used a different formula, with a different coef, and some scaling:
pe_b4xb5 = coef.iloc[3,4] * price_range * pr_b4xb5 * (1-pr_b4xb5)

A different method loops through the new price range:
X_temp = X.copy()
for price in price_range:
    X_temp['Price_4'] = price
    P_5_test = lr.predict_proba(X_temp)[:,4]
    P_5 = lr.predict_proba(X_brand)[:,4]
    delta_P = P_5_test - P_5
    pe_b4xb5 = (delta_P / P_5) / ((price - X['Price_4'].mean()) / X['Price_4'].mean())

These all produce very different results:

The vertical lines represent the price range for brand 4 in the dataset, 1.7 to 2.3.
If it helps, here are the coefs:




Coef_Brand_1
Coef_Brand_2
Coef_Brand_3
Coef_Brand_4
Coef_Brand_5




Price_1
-3.92
1.27
1.62
0.57
0.44


Price_2
0.66
-1.88
0.56
0.4
0.26


Price_3
2.42
-0.21
0.5
-1.4
-1.31


Price_4
0.7
-0.21
1.04
-1.25
-0.29


Price_5
-0.2
0.59
0.45
0.25
-1.09



Any advice would be hugely welcome - I'm still pretty new to all this side of things, and it's possible I'm missing something completely.

Greetings James, and welcome to Data Science StackExchange :) It's been a long time since I studied economics, so please be nice   Can you confirm whether your LogisticRegression model is using the default one-vs-rest (OvR) classification or the multinomial option (eg., by specifying multi_class='multinomial')? This distinction is important because it impacts how elasticities are calculated, as OvR treats each class as a separate binary classification problem, while multinomial models the probabilities jointly across all classes

Same, it's been over a decade since I studied economics! It's multinomial - it's not in the code because FutureWarning: 'multi_class' was deprecated in version 1.5 and will be removed in 1.7. From then on, it will always use 'multinomial'. Leave it to its default value to avoid this warning.

Aaah crikey, it’s the blind leading the blind ‍♂️ Well, thanks for the response. I hadn’t been aware that multi_class had passed away! I’ve got the bare bones of an answer already, now that you’ve clarified that, I’ll try to put on the finishing touches.

BTW in case you find my answer isn't good enough and you don't get another answer here, then I'd suggest asking over at Cross Validated. They have some actual economists and econometricians over there. And there is also an economics.stackexchange.com, in case you weren't aware.

Cross elasticity of demand quantifies the responsiveness of demand for one product (eg., Brand 5) to price changes in another (eg., Brand 4). While conceptually simple, its implementation using multinomial logistic regression involves nuances that can lead to differing results. This answer addresses key concerns and proposes an approach for clarity and accuracy.
Key Concepts and Definitions
In multinomial logistic regression, the probability $P(y_i = k)$ of choosing Brand $k$ is modeled as:
$$
P(y_i = k) = \frac{\exp(\beta_{k,0} + \sum_{j} \beta_{k,j} x_{i,j})}{\sum_{k'} \exp(\beta_{k',0} + \sum_{j} \beta_{k',j} x_{i,j})}
$$
where:

$\beta_{k,j}$ represents the coefficient of feature $j$ for Brand $k$.
$\beta_{k,0}$ is the intercept for Brand $k$.
$x_{i,j}$ is the price or other feature for Brand $j$.

All class probabilities are jointly modelled, ensuring that the sum of probabilities for all classes is always 1. This joint modelling captures interdependencies between probabilities, directly reflecting substitution patterns, ie., how consumers switch preferences between brands when prices change. These interdependencies are crucial for understanding cross elasticity, as they quantify how changes in one brand’s price influence demand for others.
Cross elasticity of demand for Brand $m$ with respect to the price of Brand $n$ is defined as:
$$
E_{m,n} = \frac{\partial P_m}{\partial P_n} \cdot \frac{P_n}{P_m}
$$
This measures the proportional change in the probability of selecting Brand $m$ due to a proportional change in the price of Brand $n$. Because of the multinomial setup, any change in one price influences all probabilities.
Critique of Methods
Method 1: Averaged Prices with predict_proba
This method varies Brand 4's price ($P_4$), keeping others fixed at their mean values, and uses coefficients to estimate elasticities:
pe_b4 = coefs.iloc[3,3] * price_range * (1 - pr_b4)


Strengths: Simple and intuitive; uses coefficients directly.
Weaknesses: Assumes probabilities for other brands remain fixed, oversimplifying substitution patterns and interdependencies in multinomial regression.

Side Note (connection with marginal means - not important to the overall answer - just an interesting point, I thought):
Although this method involves fixing other predictors at their mean values to isolate the effect of price changes, which conceptually resembles marginal means as calculated using statistical tools such as emmeans or lsmeans, the purpose here is distinct. Marginal means summarise the expected outcome averaged across predictor levels, often for descriptive or inferential purposes. In contrast, Method 1 focuses on deriving elasticities, which are proportional changes or derivatives of demand with respect to price. This focus on rates of change rather than averages aligns it with economic interpretation rather than purely statistical summarisation.
The connection to emmeans lies in the structural similarity of holding other predictors constant to isolate the effect of interest. However, elasticities extend this logic by embedding it within an economic framework to measure responsiveness. While both approaches involve conditioning on fixed predictor values, elasticities are inherently derivative-based and interpret demand changes relative to proportional price adjustments, making their scope and insights fundamentally different.
Method 2: Cross Coefficient with Scaling
This method includes a cross-price coefficient and scales elasticity using $(1 - P)$:
pe_b4xb5 = coefs.iloc[3,4] * price_range * pr_b4xb5 * (1 - pr_b4xb5)


Strengths: Reflects competitive effects, ie., how changes in one brand’s price influence demand for others, reflecting substitution patterns among consumers. The multinomial framework captures these substitution patterns by jointly modelling probabilities.
Weaknesses: More sensitive to small probability changes, which can exaggerate elasticity estimates.

Method 3: Delta Change in Probabilities
This iterative approach computes elasticities as proportional changes in demand:
delta_P = P_5_test - P_5
pe_b4xb5 = (delta_P / P_5) / ((price - X['Price_4'].mean()) / X['Price_4'].mean())


Strengths: Avoids reliance on coefficients; instead, focuses on observed changes in probabilities. Particularly useful for noisy datasets or sparse observations where coefficient estimates may be unreliable.
Weaknesses: Computationally intensive and may overemphasise noise in small datasets.

Recommendations
1. Focus on Observed Price Range
Limit analysis to the observed range (1.7–2.3) to ensure validity. Predictions beyond this range involve extrapolation, which may be unreliable.
2. Use Cross Coefficients
For cross elasticity, use the coefficient of the influencing brand ($\beta_{m,n}$). Scaling with $(1 - P)$ is important to account for competitive effects, ensuring that changes in one brand's price reflect interdependencies across probabilities.
3. Conduct Sensitivity Analysis
Validate outputs by comparing predicted probabilities with observed probabilities using:

Calibration plots: Compare predicted vs. observed probabilities.

Goodness-of-fit tests: Use metrics like log-likelihood or Brier scores.
Calibration plots assess how well predicted probabilities match observed outcomes, while goodness-of-fit metrics like log-likelihood and Brier scores evaluate the overall accuracy and predictive quality of the model.


4. Select a Method Based on Context

Use Method 2 for general cases with inter-brand competition and interdependent probabilities.
Prefer Method 3 for datasets with noisy or sparse observations, where observed probability changes are more reliable than coefficient estimates. This is useful when coefficient estimates are unstable or when observed probability changes may provide a clearer picture of elasticity

Insights on Results
Elasticity plots show significant variation:

Method 1: Steeper curves, indicating stronger sensitivity, but may oversimplify interdependencies.
Method 2: Smoother results, reflecting scaled probabilities and competitive effects.
Method 3: Fluctuating curves, mirroring noise in probability changes.

The dashed vertical lines (1.7–2.3) demarcate the observed price range. Results outside this range should be interpreted with caution.
The observed differences in the plot reflect how each method handles interdependencies, sensitivity to small probabilities, and extrapolation beyond the observed price range. Method 1, which fixes probabilities for other brands, produces steeper curves that may overestimate elasticity due to its oversimplified assumptions. In contrast, Method 2, by incorporating $(1 - P)$ scaling, accounts for interdependencies more effectively but may exaggerate elasticity estimates when probabilities approach 0 or 1. The fluctuations in Method 3 arise from its reliance on proportional changes in observed probabilities, amplifying noise in datasets with sparse observations or small probability values. These differences underscore the need to choose a method suited to the dataset's characteristics and to limit analysis to the observed price range (1.7–2.3) for reliable results.
This highlights the importance of understanding the assumptions and limitations of each method when interpreting elasticity estimates in applied contexts.
Summing Up
Cross elasticity in multinomial logistic regression requires careful interpretation of coefficients and probabilities. The joint modelling of probabilities ensures interdependencies between classes, making Method 2 particularly suitable for capturing these effects. Method 3, while computationally intensive, is ideal for datasets with noisy or sparse observations. Incorporating sensitivity checks and validating against observed data enhances robustness.
References

Agresti, A. (2010). Analysis of Ordinal Categorical Data. Wiley.
Train, K. E. (2009). Discrete Choice Methods with Simulation. Cambridge University Press.
Guadagni, P. M., & Little, J. D. C. (1983). "A Logit Model of Brand Choice Calibrated on Scanner Data." Marketing Science.

